# Parameter passed to Factory Pattern

Tags: parameters, factory

I have a number of optimization models and I have an interface for them.

```
public interface IOptModel
{
    public void Optimize();
}
```

Then, I have a factory class which creates different optimization models.

```
public class FactoryOptModel
{
    private Dictionary<string, OptModel> models = new Dictionary<string, OptModel>();

    public OptModel getOptModel(string spec)
    {
        foreach(OptModel model in this.models)
            if(spec == "some name")
            {
                return model_map[spec];
            }
    }
}
```

My question is that the OptModel needs two parameters to run properly. One is Problem object, and the other is Config object. I expect config object may change in the future as more models are developed. What is the proper design for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OptModel Interface:

```java
public interface OptModel {

    void optimize(String config, String Problem);
}
```

Factory Class:

```java
    public class FactoryOptModel {
    public OptModel getOptModel(String spec) {
        if (spec == "Super Optimizer") {
            return new SuperOpt("Super Config", "Super Problem");
        } else if (spec == "Fastest Optimizer") {
            return new FastestOpt("Fastest Config", "Slowest Problem");
        }
        else return null;
    }
}
```

Super Optimizer Implementation:

```java
public class SuperOpt implements OptModel{
    String config;
    String problem;
    public SuperOpt(String config, String problem){
        this.config = config;
        this.problem = problem;
    }
    public void optimize(String config, String problem){
        System.out.println("Fastest Optimizer with " + config + "and Problem " + Problem);
    }
}
```

Fastest Optimizer Implementation:

```java
public class FastestOpt implements OptModel {
    String config;
    String problem;
    public FastestOpt(String config, String problem){
        this.config = config;
        this.problem = problem;
    }
    public void optimize(String config, String Problem){
        System.out.println("Fastest Optimizer with " + config + "and Problem " + Problem);
    }
}
```

And finally, a demo:

```java
public class FactoryPatternDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        FactoryOptModel fom = new FactoryOptModel();

        OptModel superOptimizer = fom.getOptModel("Super Optimizer");
        OptModel fastestOptimizer = fom.getOptModel("Fastest Optimizer");

        superOptimizer.optimize("Super Config", "Super Problem");
        fastestOptimizer.optimize("Fastest Config", "Slowest Problem");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the construction function of Opt models, for example, `public FastestOpt(String config, String problem)' need to take in two parameters? Looks like the parameters are input again when calling optimize. Also, what design is a good choice if the configuration class may change in the future.